# How to connect datagrid item to another class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Im new here and a relative beginner with programming in C#. I have a problem with my little programm im trying to put together. it should have three windows (it´s in german but it´s easy to understand). In the first one it should have 4 cars with price, power and model in a datagrid i named DGrid. When you click on the button below the second window pops up and there you can choose what type of insurance you want and if you´re going to pay for it every year, or every half-year,ect...  and when you click the button below the third window pops up and there is the Sum you have to pay depending on your car model (which you chose in the first window) and the insurance you picked in the second window. Anyway i did the first 2 windows and it´s working properly but the problem i have is that i don´t know how to connect the car i chose in the first window(class) with the third window (where it makes the calculations). 
If i write Autos x= (Autos)DGrid.SelectedItem; in the third window, it says it doesnt recognize DGrid name (which is initialized in the first one).

So the question is: How to get the third window to use the selected item from the first one in order to make the calculations?

Here is the code - first window;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Versicherungsrechner
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Autos a1 = new Autos("Ferrari", 220, 50000);
            Autos a2 = new Autos("Lamborghini", 320, 150000);
            Autos a3 = new Autos("Maseratti", 520, 250000);
            Autos a4 = new Autos("BMW", 250, 55000);
            InitializeComponent();
            Autos[] auto = new Autos[] { a1, a2, a3, a4 };

            DGrid.ItemsSource = auto; 
        }

        public void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Details d = new Details();
            d.Owner = this;
            d.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
            d.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Second Window:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Versicherungsrechner
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Details.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Details : Window
    {
        public Details()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void AnzeigenClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Ausgabe a = new Ausgabe();
            a.Owner = this;
            a.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
            a.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

And the third:

```
    namespace Versicherungsrechner
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Ausgabe.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Ausgabe : Window
    {
        public Ausgabe()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

And the Car class:

```
    namespace Versicherungsrechner
{
    public class Autos
    {
       public string modell { get; set; }
       public double leistung { get; set; }
       public double preis { get; set; }

       public Autos(string modell, double leistung, double preis)
       {
           this.modell = modell;
           this.leistung = leistung;
           this.preis = preis;
       }


    }
}
```

Comment: Do i understand it right: You are using WPF, but you want to do everything in code-behind without XAML? (Your given sample code does not include any XAML, which is odd for WPF-related stuff.)

Comment: Well i made the window layouts with WPF in XAML, and im interested to do everything else in code-behind, although i would like to know how to do that in XAML as well. I just didnt post the XAML stuff because it´s just the layouts.

Comment: Okay, i see... Two popular choices would be to (A) [do the databinding in code-behind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or (B) - the preferred choice, although more effort up-front - create view model(s) (VMs) for your 3 windows which also reflect the (functional) relationships between those 3 windows (like, having a property for the selected car), and assign these VMs to the DataContext of the respective windows. Databind in the XAML only to the VMs in the DataContext. Any behavioral logic is implemented in the VMs, not in the controls/windows themselves.

Comment: With the example of the selected car: Create such property in your VM (either as DependencyProperty, or with INotifyPropertyChanged implementation). Let your windows A bind the respective SelectedItem to this property. Let your view model for window C also have such a property which binds (or registers an NotifyPropertyChangedEvent handler) to this property of the VM for windows A. In window C, you only bind to the property of the view model for window C. This way, you can have both window A and C open, and C still reacts when you select another car in A. (you can also use only one common VM.)

Comment: Thank you elgonzo, i have to look up what the VMs are. Im pretty new to this so my knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 0):

If you change this class...

```
public partial class Ausgabe : Window
{
    public Ausgabe()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    } 
}
```

...to this...

```
public partial class Ausgabe : Window
{
    public Autos SelectedAuto {get;set}
    public Ausgabe()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    } 
}
```

You can then change this code...

```
    public void AnzeigenClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Ausgabe a = new Ausgabe();
        a.Owner = this;
        a.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
        a.ShowDialog();
    }
```

...to this...

```
    public void AnzeigenClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Ausgabe a = new Ausgabe();
        a.SelectedAuto = DGrid.SelectedValue as Autos;
        a.Owner = this;
        a.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
        a.Setup(); // to do
        a.ShowDialog();
    }
```

And this will let the Aufgabe class have something to work with.  You can repeat this process with the other classes.

obligatory best practices note:  This was the sort of approach people used up until about 2006/2007 before data binding and Xaml became popular.  In this era, the approach is considered risky because it invites operational risk.  But for the moment it answers your question and lets you proceed with your project.

Comment: Thanks you Garry. I cant get it to work... when i change the code it still doesnt recognize the DGrid member from the first window.

Comment: Same technique.  Add a property for the DataGrid in the second and third windows and set it from the first window.  Do the same thing for each property needed.

Comment: I still get an error a.SelectedAuto = DGrid.SelectedValue as Autos;(Object reference not set to an object instance)...What is the Setup() method? I should have a car instance passed in the third window so i can then do l1.Content = x.power; where l1 is a label in the third window and x is the car that i´ve selected in the first one..And would it be easier to do it with XAML?

Comment: @user3613744  You didn't show your Xaml, but you need to set the datagrid's IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=true.  But that's a different question :) And yes, this type of code is *supposed* to be declared in Xaml.  This question is done, ask some more.  It's your first question so be sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers